# HTML5 Canvas: Drawing shapes around edges of the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm creating a basic game that draws squares at random positions on a canvas, but sometimes the shape gets cut off because it's outside of the canvas' boundaries. Can any one explain how I could go about getting the square to be drawn on the other side of the canvas (similar to how it's done in [asteroids](http://www.play.vg/games/4-Asteroids.html))? The searches I've come up with haven't been helpful. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there's an automated way to do it. Just render your squares twice, once on each side (four times if they overlap the corner).

Comment: Look up "toroidal topology"

Comment: please add more detail with your question, what you actually want, then only we will able to help you..

Comment: Are you wanting the squares to 'wrap around' as they leave the canvas, like in Asteroids? I.e. a square travelling downwards will appear at the top of the canvas when it leaves the southern boundary?

Comment: @ Ben, yes that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I've solved this one. Basically this code only draws the square whilst it is inside the canvas, if it leaves the canvas it checks which boundaries it is leaving and updates the position. The looped variable is needed because otherwise the square will be always leaving the canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('bg');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var squares = [];
squares[squares.length] = new Square(200, 200, 20, 'red', 0.785398164);

function Square(x, y, size, colour, angle)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
    this.colour = colour;
    this.speed = 5;
    this.angle = angle;
    this.looped = false;
}

Square.prototype.update = function()
{
    this.x += (Math.cos(this.angle) * this.speed);
    this.y += (Math.sin(this.angle) * this.speed);
    if (this.x < canvas.width && this.x + this.size > 0 &&
        this.y < canvas.height && this.y + this.size > 0)
    {
        this.draw();
        this.looped = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.x > canvas.width && !this.looped)
        {
            this.x = -this.size;
        }
        if (this.x + this.size < 0 && !this.looped)
        {
            this.x = this.size + canvas.width;
        }
        if (this.y > canvas.height && !this.looped)
        {
            this.y = -this.size;
        }
        if (this.y + this.size < 0 && !this.looped)
        {
            this.y = this.size + canvas.height;
        }
        this.looped = true;
    }
}

Square.prototype.draw = function()
{
    ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
}

function gameLoop()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++)
    {
        squares[i].update();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

gameLoop();

(function()
{
    // http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x)
    {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }

    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element)
    {
        var currTime = new Date().getTime();
        var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
        var id = window.setTimeout(function()
        {
            callback(currTime + timeToCall);
        }, timeToCall);
        lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
        return id;
    };

    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame) window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id)
    {
        clearTimeout(id);
    };
}());
```

I'd do a JSFiddle but requestAnimationFrame doesn't play nice with it.